# How to display table on left side of Markdown cell Jupyter Notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, markdown, jupyter

Have a table in a Markdown cell between 2 code cells, it is auto centering and I would like to to be on the left side of the cell like the text.

[image: table is aligning in center of cell, want it to be on the left]

Here's the code:

```
Let's use the first row of `indices` to classify the 0th flower in `X_test`.

species    | target
---        | ---
setosa     | 0
versicolor | 1
virginica  | 2

This cell prints the neighbor's position of closeness, index of the neighbor and that neighbor's `target` (Iris species).
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Markdown` and `display` to achieve such results. Here is the steps:

```
from IPython.core.display import Markdown
m0 = Markdown('''
Let's use the first row of `indices` to classify the 0th flower in `X_test`.
''')
m1 = Markdown('''
|species    | target | 
|-----------|:------:|
|setosa     | 0      |
|versicolor | 1      |
|virginica  | 2      |
''')
m2 = Markdown('''
This cell prints the neighbor's position of closeness, index of the neighbor and that neighbor's `target` (Iris species).
''')
```

To display, do this

```
display(m0,m1,m2)
```

Comment: This works! Is there any way to do it all in a single Markdown cell?